# Regex to match a word with numbers but not if it's numbers only

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to match a word that may contain numbers but not if it's numbers only.

For example:

`Menial` = **match**

`John124` = **match**

`V4n3ss4` = **match**

`0livia` = **match**

`3715` = **no match**

I have tried `\w*` but surprisingly, this takes a plain number as a word. I also tried other patterns with `\b` but I noticed that, for some reason, a single number is also considered a "word boundary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to force a letter somewhere in the middle of the match is to put `[A-Za-z]` in between `\w*` expressions, like this:

```
\b\w*[A-Za-z]\w*\b
```

`\b`s on both ends ensure that the matches are at word boundaries.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/NVKpXd/1)

Comment: I have tried this and @Shamus answer. Are the `\b` **really** needed or am I missing something?

Comment: @Morgan Since the expression uses `\w` next to `\b`, and we have greedy quantifiers, the match would always stretch to word's boundaries. I can't think of a case where the match would be different without `\b`s. I think it's slightly better for human readers, because they know immediately that the expression matches a single word.

Comment: Just a note that `\w` will also match underscore characters so `__a__bvf` will also be matched. Not sure if OP wants that or not. If not change `\w` to `[a-z][A-Z][0-9'`.

Comment: Should have been: change `\w` to `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]`. And the `\b` will cause strings such as `!!!!abcd123!!!` to match because the word boundary begins at the first `a` and ends at the last `3`. It might be better to use ` ^\w*[A-Za-z]\w$*` to anchor the match to the beginning and end of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*`

This is essentially "At least one non-digit character surrounded by any number of alphanumeric characters"

Comment: I think my answer may fail for strings with special characters: `-AB12CD#`